# Git commit amend in aptana studio 3?

Tags: git, aptana, aptana3, git-commit, git-amend

I just noticed when I tried to amend a commit that there is no git commit amend function in Aptana Studio 3.  Is that correct or am I missing something?

If it is indeed not there, does anyone in the community know whether it's ever going to be added or how to request it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can hit the commit button again after your commit and amend your commit. I believe aptana only prompts you if you have no files checked out at the time, if any files are checked out it doesn't prompt you and assumes you want a new commit.